# Finding neighbours of neighbours of a node - Python

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

[image]

The following is a graph that I'm using to find neighbours of green nodes.
Green nodes are in a different set called `new = [12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]`.
When I access the first green node `12`; it has it has two neighbours `15` and `21`.But `21` has another green neighbours and hence I need them to be in my list of neighbours of node `12`.This should be repeated until green nodes meet the red ones. So ultimately, the set of neighbours of node `12` should be `[0,15,21,14,16,134,23,19,3]`. can someone please help me to find this?

Comment: It'd be useful if you were to provide a list of tuples of edges or similar instead of a picture so that people can experiment easily if they choose to... (or the code you've used so far using networkx to get to a point where you have a graph, but are now experiencing difficulty with the algorithm side)

Comment: But this is something with two different types of nodes; green and red.

Comment: Right... so the code you've got that respresents the data appropriately so someone can pick it up and address the issue you have/the approach you're taking in this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-code since you didn’t at all specify how your graph works:

```
def findNeighbors (node, greens, visited = None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()

    for n in node.directNeighbors:
        # visit node if it’s new
        if n not in visited:
            visited.add(n)

            # go recursively if the new node is green
            if n in greens:
                findNeighbors(n, greens, visited)

    return visited

greenNodes = set(new)
twelve = findNodeByValue(12)
result = findNeighbors(twelve, greenNodes)
```

Comment: Thanks, Poke! But what did you mean by "for n in node.directNeighbors:" in the function?

Comment: I’m assuming that any node has a property `directNeighbors` that returns a list of all direct neighbors. For example, for the node `12`, this would be the nodes `15` and `21`.